# How to find text reuse with fuzzy match?

Tags: python, text, nlp, fuzzy-search, corpus

**I try to find, effectively, a similarity between a short phrase and a large corpus.** For example, suppose my corpus is the book   [Moby Dick](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moby-Dick_(1851)_US_edition). This book has tens of thousands of words.

In addition to that, I have a few short phrases. for example:

```
phrase1 = "Call me Ishmael" # This is the first sentence in the book exactly.
phrase2 = "Call me Isabel" # This is like the previous with changes of few letters from the third word.
phrase3 =  "Call me Is mael" #It's a similar sentence but one word split in two.
```

In addition, I have of course many other sentences that are not similar to sentences from the book.

I wonder what is the generic and effective way to identify sentences that have a sentence similar to them in the book.

What have I tried to do that seems less appropriate to me?

- I split all the input sentences into 3/4/5/6 n-grams.
- I split all the corpus sentences into 3/4/5/6 n-grams.
- Then I tried to find an approximate match (with `FuzzySet`) between all possible combinations of corpus n-grams and input n-grams (The combinations are required to grasp even cases where words have split or merged.)

It is quite clear to me that this method is very wasteful and probably also not the most accurate for my needs. I would love to understand how best to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the string edit distance algorithm. A very inefficient way is to calculate the string edit distance to all substrings of the text of a given length (e.g. the size of the input string)

Comment: @Stefan The number of all non-empty substrings is n*(n+1)/2 where n == length(Moby dick) it's billions of substrings...

Comment: Have you looked into Jaccard similarity? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Comment: @nablag but how to use that with short and very long text?

Comment: @Yanirmr I ment a sliding window approach. First compare substring 1..m, then 2..m+1, then 3..m+2, etc. As I said very inefficient, about n string edit distances. (And not obvious how to select m. It could be m=len(inputstring), but it depends on what you are expecting to find)

Comment: @Yanirmr Did you figure out a way to do this?

Comment: @WindomEarle The most effective way is to move to a database like ElasticSearch that indexes the data for that needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use corpus-based spell correction followed by fuzzyset. For spell correction, you can use a python implementation of symspell algorithm. [Here](https://github.com/topics/symspell) you can find the list of repository implementing symspell. Use symspell with compounding configuration.

- Use a speller trained on the corpus to spell correct short sentences.
- Use fuzzyset/fuzzywuzzy to find a similarity score between spell
  corrected sentence and each sentence in the corpus.
- Define a threshold by experiment, if the similarity is above the
  threshold,call it a match

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 questions: (1) what will be with the phrases that don't belong to the original corpus? (2) after the correction how to find the matches?

Comment: (1) The phases that do not belong to the corpus will remain unchanged after correction. symspell uses edit distance based correction, so if edit distance is more than configured, NO changes will be made to the phrase word.
(2) After spell correction you can match the phrase with every sentence in the corpus.

Comment: about (2) - do you any idea how to do that efficiently?